# Cauchys integral formula question

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Using Cauchys integral formula, find the value of $$\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}$$

I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly. Applying cauchys integral formula we have $2i\pi(\frac{d}{dz}e^{-z})$ evaluated at $0$. We should just get $-2i\pi$ for the answer right? I just have doubt that I understand the formula correctly $($also, I understand more work must be done about the singularity at $0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it a pole of order two?  I would apply the residue theorem, as I don't see CIF applying.  You should get $-2\pi i$, I think.

I guess, on second thought, you could be using the consequence of CIF sometimes known as Cauchy's differentiation formula.  In which case I guess you are correct.

Comment: At least in German, the differentiation formula is just called Cauchy's generalized integral formula. I think that's what op is using. The residue theorem would be slightly overkill for this simple integral, I think.